# Как перенаправить на другую страницу в Bottle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bottle

Логика такая, есть страница авторизации с  формой, получаем через метод get логин и пароль.

```
@route('/auth', method='GET')
def home():
    login = request.forms.get('login')
    paswd = request.forms.get('pass')
    check_credentials(login, paswd)
```

обработка логина и пароля.

```
def check_credentials(user, pw):
    username = "dark"
    password = "dark"
    if pw == password and user == username:
        return template('index.html')
    return template('static/templete/auth.html')
```

Не получается вернуть страницу при успешной авторизации (т.е index.html, открывается снова страница авторизации). Что я делаю не так? Нужна просто небольшая проверка, без подключения дополнительных библиотек.

Comment: `return` перед check_credentials добавьте

Comment: Спасибо огромное.  Вопрос решен.